# Text messed up with freetype

Tags: linux, fonts

Some programs have messed up text rendering, most noticeably in discord, regardless of what distro or computer I am using. Other people were having the same issue in [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/7w9c5f/fonts_are_really_screwed_up_on_linux/).

I have tried various distros, computers, and window mangers, but no matter what, fonts are always broken. The issue is likely with freetype, one of the few constants.
The solutions shown in the reddit thread did not help, although I didn't try downgrading freetype, which isn't the kind of solution I want anyway.
Although the issue has occurred everywhere, I am presently testing on Arch with DWM.

How it should look.

[image: How it should look.]

How it does look.

[image: How it looks.]

Edit: This comparison should make the difference more clear.
Top is how it normally looks, bottom is how linux looks.
How it normally looks is like bold text in comparison.
[image: Comparison]

Comment: Could you describe the difference between the two images, please? I see no difference.

Comment: I should try provide clearer images. The font appears much thinner then on windows, or then it does for other linux users ive spoken with.

Comment: I tried adding a clearer comparison.

Comment: What are your antialiasing and hinting settings?

Comment: @frabjous
I don't know how to change those settings in Arch, but testing those settings in Debian with XFCE where the issue also occurs had no effect on Discord. I'll look into how to change font settings without a GUI settings app, so I can test on Arch, but I doubt it will make a difference.

Comment: See [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Font_configuration) for how to set them in Arch. I don't use Discord, so I can't test.